# Making authenticated calls to Twitter API to avoid rate limiting

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter

I'm using Twitter API to display latest tweets from 4 different users on my page. Looks like after certain numbers of calls I get a "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request" error and tweets won't display.

After reading up on the topic online, I read that one way to avoid this limit is to make authenticated calls to the API. Anybody know how this is possible? I'm looking for a Javascript-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using OAuth? Refer to "Getting started with OAuth 2.0" by Ryan Boyd.

Comment: I'm using [this script](https://github.com/philipbeel/Tweetable/blob/master/jquery.tweetable.js) with no authentication